# How to use CountDistinct function with concatenated string?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have designed a report in SSRS 2008. (SQL Server 2008 DB)

I have 2 fields, property code and unit code.
I want to count distinct units.

```
CountDistinct(unitCode) works when I run the report for one property.
```

But when I run the report for multiple properties (and the unit code can be same in different properties) the count is wrong.

For example:

**Property table**

```
pCode    address
10       Addr1
20       Addr2
30       Addr3
```

**Unit table**

```
unitCode    pCode
101         10
102         10
101         20
103         30
```

Here unit code 101 is repeated in 2 properties.

```
CountDistinct(unitCode) is failing here.
```

So I tried

```
CountDistinct(Fields!pCode.Value & " " & Fields!unitCode.Value)
```

But it gives me an error
  **The specified operation is not valid.**

Any ideas how I can get the distinct unit counts for multiple properties?

Comment: Please share sample of your expected result.

Comment: Please post some screenshots of your report and expression, as well as the data types being used.  Using the expression exactly as you have it here works for me in a dummy report.

Comment: Are you using 2 different datasets? You can't directly reference values from the other dataset if a table is already using one. If that's the case, check out the `Lookup` function.